# Easy way to allow options only when other is present using CommandLineParserLibrary

Tags: c#, command-line-parser

I am trying to implement logic using this library: 
I have the verb `write`, and options by this scheme:

`write (-md [-p|-s] [-t]) | (-txt [-v])` - where '|' - means or (only -p OR -s is accepted (but not necessary as shown by '[]') when using -md)

Is there easy way to implement this? or should I split this to separate verbs?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering own question but it would be helpful to someone else ([source](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline/issues/246)):

You can use use `SetName` argument while declaring `OptionAttribute`:

```
internal class Options
{
    [Option("username", SetName = "auth")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Option("password", SetName = "auth")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Option("guestaccess", SetName = "guest")]
    public bool GuestAccess { get; set; }
}
```

Now `username` and `password` can be used together, but `guestaccess` is alone within "guest" set, so it can not be used with options from other sets.